# Default exim not using the from address being passed to it

Tags: centos, exim, sympa

After replacing postfix with exim (defaults)
now the from address on mail sent by an application (sympa) is being changed
xyz@goodstuff.whatever to xyz@hostname

Why? 
no rewrite rules seem to be declared

Please help

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If your system is using a simple /etc/exim/exim.conf, add this simple line:

```
primary_hostname = goodstuff.whatever
```

Restart exim after you change the config file.

I don't know if CentOS EPEL rpms (assuming that's what you used) look inside any file to set that variable or if woudl have to be manually added by you.